# \bibliography command not working with cls file (gsag3jnl template from overleaf)

Tags: bibliographies

I wanted to use the template from overleaf gsag3jnl, but i see that even in the web browser from overleaf, the bibliography command does not work.
This is the link of the template:

- https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-preparing-your-submission-to-g3-genes-genomes-genetics-using-overleaf/vffkrpmjrcgf

EDIT1:
`\bibliography{}` is not printing anything! I've read other posts with the same issue and they were related to packages which I have already installed.

my document is like:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,twoside]{gsag3jnl}

\articletype{inv}

\begin {document}

\section

\section

\bibliography{my_bib_file}

\end{document}
```

Latex template compiles perfectly and does not throw any warnign, and it does not show any bibliography!

Comment: Never ever show images of code, paste in the actual code. Please explain what you mean by `the bibliography command does not work`? Do you get an error, or did you forget to actually cite something?

Comment: No, in the template the \bibliography command does not show the bibliography. (the bib file). I think that is easier if you could check the template to see that the \bibliograhpy command does not work

Comment: As I said, show your code. Note that we generally never go to external sites for examples as they rot over time and thus your question will not be useful to others. When using bibtex no bibliography is generated unless you actually cite something. Additionally, as this is overleaf, does your document actually compile without any errors? A lot of overleaf users tend to ignore compilation errors

Comment: @daleif ok, see edit 1

Comment: As I mentions there are NO CITATIONS IN THAT EXAMPLE! You need to `\cite` something before it end up in the bibliography.

Comment: @daleif even if i write \cite or \citep (it says in the template to use \citep) there is a question mark in the citation and nothing at the bottom, where the whole bibliography should appear

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment, I don't have your `my_bib_file.bib` or know where you put it. Using the overleaf template with the sample `.bib` that comes with the template, this works just fine

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,twoside]{gsag3jnl}
\articletype{inv}
\begin {document}
\cite{rodelsperger2014characterization}
\bibliography{example-bibliography}
%\bibliography{my_bib_file}
\end{document}
```

so either you are doing something wrong, or there is something you are not telling us.

[image]

Comment: I am sory... that was my mistake. I wanted to print the bibliography without citing any paper...\nocite or  \nocitep not working :(:(

Comment: @Maik123456789 read up on that command it needs an argument: `\nocite{*} `